# Flutter - How to get country name from country code?

Tags: dart, flutter

I can easily get the country code using--

```
Locale myLocale = Localizations.localeOf(context);
final String countryCode = myLocale.toString();
```

However, my trouble is retrieving it's corresponding "display name"

In other words, Objective-C has something like this:

```
    NSString *countryName = [[NSLocale myLocale] displayNameForKey: NSLocaleIdentifier value: identifier];
```

Is there such an equivalent when it comes to Flutter/Dart?

Answer (score 0):

You can add Country code picker package in your pub file
**country_code_picker: 1.1.1**